# Calling microservices from shell script

Tags: shell, unix, microservices

Team,
For our server maintainance we used to stop microservices and after that need to start servers as well microservices, I am currently doing all automation via shell script, but issue is, I am able to kill my 5 microservice pID and able to kill it, but start of microservice not running.

I mean when I go manually to that path, it starts, but using shell script it does not work.

I tried below (kill - stopping works fine) but it does not starting even one

```
#!/bin/sh
isMicroserviceRunning()
    {
            SCHEDPID=$(ps aux|grep -i service |grep -v grep|awk '{print $2}'|wc -l)
            if [[ $SCHEDPID -gt 1 ]]
            then
                    return 0
            else
                    return 1
            fi
    }
    
    killService()
    {
      pid=$(ps aux | grep 'service' |grep -v grep |awk '{print $2}')
      kill -9 $pid
    }
    
    if ! isMicroserviceRunning
    then
            sleep 1
            . /opt/alfresco/microservice/service_1/start-service_1.sh
            sleep 1
            . /opt/alfresco/microservice/service_2/start-service_2.sh
            sleep 1
            . /opt/alfresco/microservice/service_3/start-service_3.sh
            sleep 1
            . /opt/alfresco/microservice/service_4/start-service_4.sh
            sleep 1
            . /opt/alfresco/microservice/service_5/start-service_5.sh
    
    else
            echo "Microservice for $1 already running, so nothing to do"
    
    fi
```

What changes I had to do to make these 5 microservices to work perfectly via shell script?
Yes while starting microservices it generates logs.

Please help.

Comment: Have you kept space after dot in path for executing start-service ?

Comment: @shaktirajsinh Jadeja :: Yes I have kept space (Even tried with sh <shellpath> ,  .  <shellpath>

Comment: you can try bash <path-to-script>/strart-service.sh

Comment: Try  `ps aux | grep ser[v]ice` to avoid  `| grep -v grep` ....  Try `ps -C command ho pid` instead of all your `... | ... | ...` line .. ( or `pidof command`)

Comment: It's not clear what shell you are using. You tagged the question only with _shell_, but are using constructs which are not valid in POSIX shell. Please update the question by providing a suitable tag.

Comment: If it's a shell script, consider putting a shebang at the top so everyone/everything knows which shell it requires, then add a PATH after that instead of repeating ridiculously long paths to individual commands, then run it through shellcheck.net